# Jedi and Lothal Temple

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In episodes 12 and 13, Season 4 of [Rebels TV series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels), [Jedi Temple on Lothal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lothal_Jedi_Temple) is depicted not only as a powerful nexus of the Force,

> but also as an gateway to "world between worlds" connecting various places in space and time, thus allowing manipulation of past and presumably future events and giving tremendous power to those who use it. Even Emperor himself was interested in gaining control of it .

Since Jedi presumably built the place, they should have known how to operate it.

> Yet never before or after this temple is mentioned, although it could be presumably very useful in Clone Wars to discern who exactly is Sidious or to save certain masters like Windu, prevent Order 66 and change events that brought misery in the Galaxy.

Question is, why Jedi didn't use Temple on Lothal if they had such power at their disposal ?

Comment: My impression from watching the last few episodes is that the Temple in Lothal was forgotten over the centuries. Also, as already discussed extensively in this site, the Jedi had become very arrogant but also they were blinded by the Dark Side, so perhaps it never occurred to them to use or look for the Temple.

Comment: @Loki Care to write full answer ?

Comment: What I'm interested in is how the Emperor seems to have his own portal into the other World, mere scenes after he's shown talking to the Minister trying to figure out what the Lothal temple is about. Ezra opens the Lothal portal and goes to the World, then the Emperor just magically has his own portal minutes later, too? Seems a little fishy

Comment: @rs.29 Actually the wookieepdia article on the Temple (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lothal_Jedi_Temple) seems to contradict my assumption. Apparently the Temple was known to the Jedi even up to the Clone Wars. So, probably this is just bad writing...

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think your comment is very interesting and warrants a new question on its own. Actually, I was also wondering about how the Emperor got in the "World" myself.

Comment: @Loki: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182529/

Comment: As I remember, the rebels visited a Jedi temple on Lothal in the first season, and the synopsis of "Path of the Jedi" January 5, 2015 says that Kanan takes Ezra the to a hidden Jedi temple on Lothal.  Is that the same hidden Jedi temple or a different Jedi temple?  If it is the same temple, why don't the Jedi know of it's great powers as in the 4th season?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_Rebels_episodes#Season_4_(2017%E2%80%9318)