# How does the Emperor know about, and get to, this place?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In *Star Wars Rebels*, Season 4 Episode 13: "A World Between Worlds", it is revealed that

> the Jedi Temple on Lothal hides a portal to another dimension between life and death, time and space.

But how does the Emperor

> open his own portal to this dimension?

Mere scenes earlier, the Emperor is shown talking to Minister Hydan,

> who is trying to figure out what the Lothal Jedi temple is all about and how to access it. The Emperor gives him permission to continue exploring.

The Minister knows

> there is some kind of portal related to the Mortis gods, he just doesn't know how to open it.

But Ezra

> is able to open the portal,

And is then forced to flee into it when Stormtroopers discover him.  Then minutes later, the Emperor is shown

> opening his own portal and communicating with Ezra.

How did the Emperor know

> about this dimension, let alone how to open his own portal to it so quickly?

The Emperor seems to have trouble stepping through on his own, he needs a connection to Ezra

> which he uses some kind of Force-controlled Flames to reach Ezra, but Ahsoka (who Ezra pulls out of time following her fight with Vader on Malachor) cuts him off with her lightsaber, forcing him back to his side of the portal.

Seems a little fishy to me, just to drive the plot.

Comment: This was one of the points that bugged me in the episode as well. My +1 for asking and let's hope someone knows the answer...

Comment: "How does the Emperor know about, and get to, this place?" He used the Force.

Comment: In Clone Wars: Season 6.13 "Sacrifice" - we see that Palpatine has the ability to establish Force connections with others. It's possible he did something similar here w/ Ezra that he did w/ Yoda. Dave Filoni confirms in an episode of Rebel Recon that the Emperor did know about the World Between Worlds already - https://youtu.be/_XGJd_g1zDA?t=112

Comment: Hmm. I can understand that the Emperor would have studied Jedi and Sith history, so he might have known about the Mortis gods beforehand. But, would that be enough to know about the actual existence of the other dimension and what he can do with it? Filoni didn't elaborate on that. Let alone know how to open a portal to it? And how could he have made a connection with Ezra beforehand (in Clone Wars, he made a connection to Yoda through Dooku)? Still seems like some big plot holes for such a short time frame.

Comment: When you gaze into the abyss, the abyss gazes also. Ezra put himself in a Force nexus, and even opened himself up enough to look through the windows. He made himself vulnerable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Anakin visited Mortis and had memories of that place, which he undoubtedly told Palpatine once he became his apprentice. It's also possible that Vader seeing Ahsoka get plucked out of space-time triggered him to inform Palpatine, who then started looking into it, thus finding the temple. Like a time loop.

Comment: -1 For overuse of spoiler tags.

Comment: @Lexible why the -1? I posted this question just after the episode first aired, so the spoilers were warranted at the time. If you don't like them, feel free to remove them now.

Answer (score 4):

### Vader and the *Dark Arts* <sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup>No, not the Voldemort kind...</sub>

While very vague (as of now) the [Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank) gives us a few little details into the Lothal Jedi temple and the Emperor.

We know from an earlier episode that after Kanan and Ezra first discover the temple, they return with Ahsoka in search of answers. At the temple, they're attacked by Darth Vader and his inquisitors, and after gaining control of the Temple Vader says:

> “My Master will be most pleased with this discovery,”
> <sub>[Lothal Jedi Temple - Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/lothal-jedi-temple)</sub>

While this doesn't explain how the Emperor learns about the temple in the first place, it informs us he's aware it is of great significance, given the Emperor's happiness even though they've once again failed to capture Phoenix Squadron.
The Emperor's prior knowledge of the supposed "power" is again re-stated later:

> [Veris Hydan] and the Emperor believed that this Temple, and a painting of the Mortis gods on its exterior, were a gateway to untold power.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Note that what led Veris Hydan here (as he states many times in the most recent few episodes) was discoveries he'd made in the Jedi archive. It is likely that the Emperor and Hydan had read things which led them to believe this great power was held here.

Finally, to gain access to the temple after Ezra had entered it, the Emperor used (what Star Wars is calling) *dark arts*:

> The Emperor, through dark arts, found Bridger and Tano in the Temple, and almost succeeded in using them to gain entrance. The Jedi escaped, however, and the Temple collapsed.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Comment: Hmmmmm In all honesty I always thought that the emperor we saw was not the current one, but a "future" one from a time when ezra did not return and collapse the temple.

Comment: From all the extras I'd seen and read, everything suggests it's the OG Emperor we've seen the whole time, no time travel silliness.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Emperor somehow knew about "world between worlds" (from Sith and Jedi lore) and could sense it in the Force as this place is strong nexus. He also knew that gateway to this world could be opened from within Jedi temple on Lothal, so he sent Hydan and others there. What he didn't know is how to actually open gateway in the Temple, but sensed when Bridger and later Tano entered this dimension.

Following is a speculation, but as Emperor could not enter "world between worlds" from his study on Coruscant, he used Sith sorcery on Ezra and Ahsoka to **make them open portal to him**. He uses Sith sorcery (blue flames and rope) to grab Ezra and pull himself into this dimension and almost succeeds with his one hand in. But then Tano cuts the rope and both of them flee from "world between worlds" so Emperor could not grab to anyone and vast power of the dimension is denied to him.

Of course, question and possible plot hole remains, [why Jedi didn't use the Temple](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182485/jedi-and-lothal-temple) , if they built it and knew how to operate it, for greater good of the Galaxy.

Comment: I think the REASON could easily be seen as being in the jedi doctrine....as Ashoka said some things are meant to happen and jedi are naturally passive there.